# How can I prevent Adobe Reader DC from always opening maximized windows

Tags: adobe-acrobat, adobe-reader, pdf-reader

Recently, Adobe Reader DC have started to always opening documents in maximized windows covering the entire desktop.

How can I turn it off?

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be fixable only by changing the `irandom` registry entry to 0x1000.

Set the registry key `https://forums.adobe.com/message/8149543#8149543/irandom` to hex 0x00001000 (decimal 4096), as [described here in 2015](https://forums.adobe.com/message/8149543).

For Acrobat DC (not Reader), there is a [different key](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2002638) to make it remember the last window size/placement:

`HKCU\Software\Adobe\Adobe Acrobt\DC\ExitSection`, change `bLastExitNormal` from 1 to 0